# How to get the item color and size in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can someone help me to get the item color and size of specific item.
I got the id of item called "custcol_coloroption" with value of 8. how can i translate that to value Ex. Black,White and etc. Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell me  how did you get this `custcol_coloroption` internal id. can you provide some code snippet. It doesn't seem to be a matrix field. I suspect it is a transaction column field.

Comment: @Rockstarvar ir = nlapiLoadRecord('itemreceipt',id);       ir[0].getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_coloroption', 1);

Comment: @Rockstar Here's some info of item. countryofmanufacture: "PE"
currency: "USD"
custcol_coloroption: "8"
custcol_columnforcolor: "8"
custcol_columnforsize: "1"
custcol_item_type: "1"
custcol_size: "1"

Comment: I assume `ir[0].getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_coloroption', 1);` returns you a value of `8`. You also can use `ir[0].getLineItemText('item', 'custcol_coloroption', 1);` to get the text value associated with that attribute.

Comment: @Rockstar It throws error TypeError: Cannot read property 'nlapiGetLineItemText' of undefined

Comment: @Rockstar i mean TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLineItemText' of undefined

Comment: BTW I think you're loading a single record so no need of `ir[0]` :) have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ir = nlapiLoadRecord('itemreceipt',id);
var attributeid = ir.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_coloroption', 1); // returns you the id
var attributename = ir.getLineItemText('item', 'custcol_coloroption', 1); // returns you the text associated with that attribute
```

Comment: Can i ask other question here, regarding to location of item?

Comment: Its better to create a separate thread rather mixing up all together. ;)

Comment: Most likely correct.. You have to make sure in Netsuite you work with Text and Value of a record. The value is what Netsuite uses and the text is the label hanging to it. So in user3628301's case, the value would be 8 and the text "black" (or whatever text is in there).